# Changes in Observable not reflected in View

Tags: angular, rxjs

I basically followed [this guide](http://blog.angular-university.io/how-to-build-angular2-apps-using-rxjs-observable-data-services-pitfalls-to-avoid/) to implement an Observable data service.

In a store class (`ItemsStore`), I have my `BehaviorSubject` which holds a list of the items

```
items:BehaviorSubject<List<Item>> = new BehaviorSubject(List([]));
```

A component uses that store in the template as follows:

```
<ion-slide *ngFor="let item of itemStore.items | async" >
  [...]
</ion-slide>
```

Now this works fine when the app loads - all my items are displayed. However, If I add an item to the `BehaviorSubject` using the following code in the store class:

```
this.items.next(this.item.getValue().push(newItem));
```

This is not reflected in the view. I was under the impression, that change handling is done automagically by angular2, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

How do I detect and handle such changes, so that they are reflected in the view?

Answer (score 2):

I'm suspicious the problem is in the way you call:

```
this.items.next(this.item.getValue().push(newItem));
```

I don't know what `this.item.getValue()` returns but if `push()` method is the same as [`Array.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) it returns new length (the important thing is it doesn't return `this.items` with the new item appended).

The `async` pipe is defined as:

> The async pipe subscribes to an Observable or Promise and returns **the latest value it has emitted**.

So when you call `this.items.next(...)` the async pipe receives just the new length and tries to iterate it with `*ngFor`.

If `this.item` holds `<List<Item>>` then you probably want to call:

```
this.item.getValue().push(newItem);
this.items.next(this.item);
```

Btw, the [`asObservable()`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/Subject.ts#L117) method is used to hide the fact that you're working with `Subject`. Subject let's you call `next()` or `complete()` which is something that you don't want other users to mess with. For this reason it's better to pass everywhere just an `Observable` and keep `Subject` only for yourself where you know you need it.

Answer (score 1):

The items property should be Observable, but you set it as BehaviourSubject type. In your link there is:

```
@Injectable()
export class TodoStore {
    private _todos: BehaviorSubject<List<Todo>> = new BehaviorSubject(List([]));

    public todos: Observable<List<Todo>> = this._todos.asObservable();

    constructor(private todoBackendService: TodoBackendService) {
        this.loadInitialData();
    }
    ...
}
```

so assuming you followed this tutorial you should do something like this:

```
private _items: BehaviorSubject<List<Item>> = new BehaviorSubject(List([]));
public items: Observable<List<Item>> = this._items.asObservable();
```

Comment: You are definitely right, missed that completely. Although I don't understand why I have to call `.asObservable()` when `BehaviourSubject`extends `Observable`. And unfortunately it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it - and it was a very stupid mistake - shame on me. `ItemsStore` gets injected in two different classes, and since the *Dependency Injection* creates an instance for each injection - well, then we have two of the same kind where there should only be one.

Moving the dependency (`ItemsStore`) to the global providers array solved the problem.