# Angular component: Can I use an Observable instead EventEmitter as @Output() property?

Tags: angular, rxjs, eventemitter

[angular 2.4.5]

I tried and it seems to work like an EventEmitter:

- My component from outside:

  ```js
  <split (visibleTransitionEnd)="log($event)"></split>
  ```
- Inside the component:

  ```js
  @Output() visibleTransitionEnd: Observable<string>
  observer: Observer;

  constructor() {
    const myObs = new Observable(observer => this.observer = observer);

    this.visibleTransitionEnd = myObs
      .map(x => '> ' + x + ' <')
      .debounceTime(20)
      .do(() => console.log('here we are!'));
  }
  ```
- Then I can call inside component:

  ```js
  // needed condition because if nobody subscribe 'visibleTransitionEnd' > no observer!
  if(this.observer) this.observer.next('test');
  ```

[View this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/nRYhoF?p=preview)

I like this because there's no subscription inside my component.

But is it a bad way to achieve this? What's the risk/wrong?

Is it better to use a `Subject`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delegation: EventEmitter or Observable in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34376854/delegation-eventemitter-or-observable-in-angular)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, in your situation you could use `EventEmitter` or `Subject`. You can see that an `EventEmitter` is just like `Subject` (although it's recommended to use `EventEmitter` if you can). https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/%40angular/facade/src/async.ts

The `Observable.create` (or `new Observable()`) is not intended to be used like this. The inner function should emit values to the observer and return a tear down function (to release resources or whatever). Not to be kept as a property.
However, I'm not sure what consequences it might have (memory leaks?).

So rather use `Subject` instead:

```js
export class SplitComponent implements OnDestroy {
  @Output() visibleTransitionEnd: Observable<string>
  visibleTransitionEndObserver: Subject;

  constructor() {
    const subject = new Subject();

    this.visibleTransitionEnd = subject.asObservable()
      .map(x => '> ' + x + ' <')
      .debounceTime(20)
      .do(() => console.log('here we are!'));
  }

  // ...
}
```

Comment: thx, I've updated my plunker following answers and it works well with a `Subject` without adding `asObservable` operator, why did you add it?

Comment: @bertrandg See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39703167/changes-in-observable-not-reflected-in-view/39721493#39721493 and https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/asobservable.md

Answer (score 19):

`EventEmitter` just extends `Subject`, so this is no surprise (and I also saw this already in Dart).

They use their own class to be able to alter the implementation later without breaking existing code.

So it might not be the best idea to circumvent this abstraction. If you are aware of the disadvantage and willing to accept it, you can of course do it.

Comment: Do you know if it would be OK to use .publishReplay/publish + refCount and mark it as @Output?

Comment: I don't know, but shouldn't be hard to find out.

Comment: Opened a feature request to expose observables as Output properties in a future safe way: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/23435

Answer (score 2):

2 reasons to choose EventEmitter

1. Angular `EventEmitter` can make sure to delivery event asynchronously if needed. It's good for responsive user experience.
2. Encapsulate the underline implementation. If someday, next version of Angular would update event binding which depends on something new of `EventEmitter`. It would be disaster of your project if `Subject` extensively used. Not sure about this. But should be avoided.

Angular `EventEmitter` extends RxJS `Subject` with only 3 methods so far: 1) `constructor()`, 2) `subscribe(next, error, complete)` and 3) new method `emit(value) {super.next(value);}`

If you `new EventEmitter(true)`, it will deliver events asynchronously

```ts
    constructor(isAsync = false) {
        super();
        this.__isAsync = isAsync;
    }
```

`EventEmitter.subscribe()` does something to **async** delivery event according to `this._isAsync`.

Answer (score 2):

I want to point out an advantage of using Observable for output interface is
you can basically throw in any observable you want

So let say if you if you have an event that will only fire when the form is valid and pass on the value.

With event emitter you'll have to define extra Emitter instance to handle that

```
@Output validValue = new EventEmitter()
this.form.valueChanges.pipe(tap(value=>{
if(ths.form.valid) 
   validValue.emit(value)
})).subscribbe()
```

Using Observable as event emission you can simply do this

```
@Output() validValue=this.form.valueChanges.pipe(filter(_=>this.form.valid))
```